# On Behalf Of flow: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'xxx']

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

The following code snippet works with data from Tenant1, but fails with the Thumbprint error when using data for Tenant2.  Any thoughts on what might be different?  The App Registration on each tenant looks the same.

The token in the UserAssertion is the string coming Outlook `Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync()`.

I'm write back-end code to access the user's Outlook data via Graph using Delegated permissions (/me/... URLs). Application permissions are not usable in this case.

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;

            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<<clientid>>")
               .WithClientSecret("<<clientSecret>>")
               .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "<<tenantID>>")
               .Build();
            UserAssertion ua = new UserAssertion(token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
            string[] scopeList = new string[1] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopeList.Select(s => s), ua).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logfile.LogError("", ex);
            }
```

Comment: Hmm.. does getUserIdentityToken produce a token meant for your API?

Comment: getUserIdentityToken is also useful for passing to a back-end API that can then be validated against a Microsoft endpoint to allow that back-end API to trust the calling application to be trusted for the user.

Answer (score 0):

PEBKAC.  I need to pass the token from Office.auth.getAccessToken()... Then things works correctly.